# Why was Kate Wilson so afraid of water?

Tags: hydrophobia

The video game [*Hydrophobia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophobia_(video_game)) (2010) indicates that our protagonist was afraid of water. Throughout the development of the story, this is backed up by her reactions to the slowly sinking ship and the vast amounts of water that often hinder her path. There are some hints to her past, indicating some trauma somehow connected to water.

Was it ever conclusively revealed where that fear came from?

Comment: No. ...but consider that the world has been consumed by water in this game. Also consider that they tried to throw "hydro" into everything because the game was an exhibition for the HydroEngine fluid dynamics engine, emphasizing player vs environment interactions. A good way to get a person more interested in these interactions is by giving someone rabies. (Just kidding, hydrophobia.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game's designer, Rob Hewson has stated in an interview that the *flashbacks* you see in the game relate directly to the root-cause of Kate's fear of water, in particular an incident involving a drowning.

> **Q.** **Other than being an engineer, is there anything special about protagonist Kate Wilson?**
>
> **RH**: *We wanted a lead character that starts out as a reluctant hero, somebody with flaws who has room to grow and evolve. We took
> inspirations from protagonists like Ripley in the first Alien movie;
> we really wanted to get away from the beautiful but deadly stereotype
> for a female lead. **Kate has been deeply affected by some traumatic
> experiences in her past giving her an intense fear of drowning, and
> although her external battle is with the neo-Malthusians, she is also
> fighting internal demons.***
>
> **Q.** **How does Wilson’s fear of water affect gameplay?**
>
> **RH**: ***Kate will experience hallucinations and flashes of the traumatic memory which is the route cause of her phobia.** As Kate endures she
> begins to learn to use the flow of the water against her enemies, and
> ultimately by facing up to her own nightmares she will begin to unlock
> the power to control the water itself.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview: Hydrophobia’s Rob Hewson](https://gematsu.com/2010/04/interview-hyrdrophobias-rob-hewson#4U8vQiIlgoypQ4QL.99)</sup></sub>

Right at the start of the game you see a young girl apparently drowning (while singing the obligatory [*creepy nursery rhyme*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CreepyChildrenSinging)). In a later scene you learn that this is her...

> ... sister ...

... when you see a framed photo on the desk in Kate's room.

Answer (score 4):

The dream sequence at the beginning of the game shows a woman's corpse floating underwater in a cave.

It is revealed that Kate is having this dream, so she must have been traumatized by watching a woman ([apparently her sister](https://www.giantbomb.com/kate-wilson/3005-15986/)) drown.